# How to selectively emit hot (shared) observables in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, reactivex

In my code, I have a hot observable (cold observable piped through the share() operator) emitting values with identifiers (i.e. payload type contains an "id" string property). A bunch of observers on this then filter the emitted values based on said id.

I'm now think my code is taking a huge performance hit, since every observer has to filter every value that gets emitted. Or rather, a new filtered observable is created every time I need a new observer to subscribe to the shared observable. The code kind of looks like this:

```
const source = new Observable();
const sharedObservable = source.pipe(share());
sharedObservable
    .pipe(filter(payload => payload.id === "id1"))
    .subscribe(observerOne);
sharedObservable
    .pipe(filter(payload => payload.id === "id2"))
    .subscribe(observerTwo);
// etc.
```

My initial solution is to create my own type of hot/shared observable that handles the filtering based on an internal map from ids to lists of observers that should receive the payloads. That would cut down on the cost of having to run some predicate filter function for every single observer that subscribes. Underneath the observable would look something like (or vaguely like) this:

```
class FilteredHotObservable {
    constructor(sourceObservable) {
        this.observerMap = new Map();
        this.source = sourceObservable;
        this.source.subscribe(payload => {
            const observers = this.observerMap.get(payload.id);
            observers.forEach(observer => observer.next(payload));
        });
    }

    subscribe(observer, desiredIdToFilterBy) {
        const observers = this.observerMap.get(desiredIdToFilterBy);
        observers.push(observer);
    }
}
```

Before I go and implement this though, I was wondering if there's already a proper way of handling this scenario. In other words, does RxJS already have a mechanism (e.g. a special Subject, a fancy operator) to facilitate this sort of scalable "filtered & shared" observable?

**DISCLAIMER: The names and syntax of the code snippets above are not accurate with what I'm actually doing. They're just samples for the sake of this post.**

Edit:
Here are actual numbers regarding the emission-handling latency of using the `filter` operator. For "PostFilterLatency", emitted payloads are filtered by ids that correspond to single observers on the shared observable. For "PreFilterLatency", emissions are manually filtered via id->Observer map, then observer.next() is subsequently called with the appropriate payload. The numbers are the time is took from when the payloads were emitted to when they were handled by their corresponding observers (time is in milliseconds).

```
ObserverCount  PostFilterLatency  PreFilterLatency
-------------  -----------------  ----------------
1              0                  0
10             0                  0
100            0.03               0
1000           0.039              0.001
10000          1.1849             0.0005
100000         19.90902           0.002
```

Edit: here's a [link](https://github.com/KeijiBranshi/npm-packages/blob/master/rxjs-filter-test/index.js) to the code I used to run these tests.

Comment: I would suggest that you investigate whether your using `filter` will incur "a huge performance hit". I'm unconvinced that it will be a bottleneck. And if it's not, you'd be solving a problem that doesn't need solving. Also, `FilteredHotObservable` is probably not the best name for that class, as it fulfils no part of the observable contract. Anyway, `FilteredHotObservable` pretty similar to putting another `share` after the `filter`.

Comment: I don't think it's `filter` itself that creates the performance hit. It's the fact I'm making a _n_ calls to it when I could just be making 1 (_n_ being the number of observers). This is because the source observable just calls `observer.next()` for every observer, who then call `filter()` (see the first code snippet in the post). If i could filter before `observer.next()` gets called in the source observable, wouldn't it scale the number of filter operations needed from O(n) down to O(1)? I hope this makes sense

Comment: Essentially, I need my shared source observable to act as a broker to the observers it emits to. Otherwise, each observer is responsible for sifting through the emissions themselves.

Comment: As for the investigation you recommended, the bottleneck was determined prior to this post. My observable emission latency starts to spike upon addition of the filtering mechanism (see first code snippet in the main post). You're right that it could be due to something else, but I'm unsure of where else to look since `filter` is the only operator called between when the source observable emits and when the observers receive. 

Thank you for responding by the way! Any thing helps with getting to the bottom of this -_-

Comment: Could you include in your question indicative numbers for the number of filters and the number of observers per filter? If the former is low - relative to the latter - just placing another `share` after each of the filters might suffice.

Comment: The number of filters will be about ~200, and there will only be about 1-2 observers per filter. The counts being so close is what prompted me to just stick with managing multiple observers and skipping the `filter` call.

Comment: there isn't something like this in rxjs because what you're doing is against the intentions of rxjs.  This shouldn't be a single shared subject filtered by many subscribers, it should be distinct subjects with the appropriate subscribers. you're essentially recreating the problems presented by global event brokering systems that rxjs intended to solve. in any event, a core tenant of rxjs is that the subject is unaware of the particulars os its subscribers